# ```XLSX.writeFile``` does not download the workbook in my file system

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sheetjs

I am trying to download a `json` as `xlsx` using `Sheetjs`. I am successfully able to create `worksheet` and `workbook` but the `ẁriteFile` function does not seem to do anything with the `workbook`. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my code:

```html
  <v-card color="primary" dense>
    <v-card-title class="white--text pa-2 min-height">
      <h3 class="text-xs-center px-2" data-test-id="DataTableTitle">{{ title(tableId) }}</h3>

      <v-spacer />

      <v-btn
        v-for="action in headerActions(tableId)"
        :key="action.title"
        data-test-id="action-button"
        @click="callActionOrRouteTo(action, tableId)"
      >
        {{ action.title }}
      </v-btn>

      <v-btn @click="onExport">EXPORT TO XLSX</v-btn>
    </v-card-title>
  </v-card>
```

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import DataTableRouting from '@/components/data-tables/DataTableRouting.vue';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

export default {
  name: 'DataTableTitleBar',
  extends: DataTableRouting,
  props: {
    tableId: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      title: 'dataTables/title',
      headerActions: 'dataTables/headerActions',
      columns: 'dataTables/columns',
      dataItems: 'dataTables/tableItems',
    }),
  },
  data: () => ({
    jsonData: null,
  }),
  methods: {
    exportToCSV(dataItems) {
      this.jsonData = dataItems.map(row => {
        const outputRow = {};
        Object.entries(row).forEach(([key, column]) => {
          outputRow[key] = column.value;
        });
        console.log(outputRow);
        return outputRow;
      });
    },
    onExport() {
      this.exportToCSV(this.dataItems(this.tableId));
      console.log(this.jsonData);
      const animalWS = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.jsonData);
      console.log(animalWS);
      const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
      console.log(wb);
      XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, animalWS, 'animals');
      XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'book.xlsx', { type: 'file' });
    },
  },
};
```

I expect that on clicking the button a `xlsx` file should be automatically downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the problem. It was my browser settings that were blocking the download. But now it works!

Comment: Please mention exactly what settings were blocking the download so that it helps others too.